# Final subclass with a superclass overridable method called from constructor - Spotbugs

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, spotbugs

If a final subclass calls a superclass overridable method from the constructor, [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) reports a bug (see note below for details).

Is this expected or is it an issue?

For example:

```
public class SuperClass {

    private final int id;

    public SuperClass(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

public final class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    private final String name;

    public SubClass(int id, String code) {
        super(id);
        this.name = getId() + code; // Spotbugs repot this line as a bug
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Reports:

```
[ERROR] Low: Overridable method getId is called from constructor new SubClass(int, String).
[SubClass] At SubClass.java:[line ?] MC_OVERRIDABLE_METHOD_CALL_IN_CONSTRUCTOR
```

**Note:**

Since [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) 4.5.0.0 bug detector `FindOverridableMethodCall` was added (see [details](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#mc-an-overridable-method-is-called-from-a-constructor-mc-overridable-method-call-in-constructor)):

> **MC: An overridable method is called from a constructor**
> **(MC_OVERRIDABLE_METHOD_CALL_IN_CONSTRUCTOR)**
>
> Calling an overridable method during in a constructor may result in
> the use of uninitialized data. It may also leak the reference of
> the partially constructed object. Only static, final or private
> methods should be invoked from a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, there is a recent open [issue](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1812) related to this case:

> False positive for MC_OVERRIDABLE_METHOD_CALL_IN_CONSTRUCTOR in final class

There is also a [pull request](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/pull/1813) to fix this bug.